# Loading .dat file into one list and count entities in it

Tags: python, list, count

I have a .dat file with the following:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 1
```

I'm trying to get this all into one list and then count the number of 1's and 0s.

I've got the code so far:

```py
with open('image.dat', 'r') as a:
    for line in a:
        b = [line.strip()]
        print(b)
    c = b.count(0)
```

This just gives me:

```
['0 0 0 0 1 1']
['1 1 0 1 0 0']
['0 0 1 1 0 0']
['0 1 1 1 1 1']
['0 1 0 0 0 1']
['1 1 0 1 0 1']
0
```

I'm new to coding and I've tried everything.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Just initialize `b` as empty list before loop and use `b += line.strip().split()`.

Comment: `with open('image.dat', 'r') as a: text = a.read(); zeros = a.count("0"); ones = a.count("1"))`

Answer (score 0):

To load the data into one list, you can use `list.extend` method, for example:

```
data = []
with open('image.dat', 'r') as a:
    for line in a:
        data.extend(map(int, line.split()))

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Then:

```
print('Number of 0:', data.count(0))
print('Number of 1:', data.count(1))
```

Prints:

```
Number of 0: 18
Number of 1: 18
```

---

EDIT: To load the data as list of lists:

```
lines = []
with open('image.dat', 'r') as a:
    for line in a:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        lines.append(list(map(int, line.split())))

print(lines)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the whole thing in a list and each line in its own list within that list if you get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can just count the number of times the string `'0'` (or `'1'`) accures within the file:

```
with open("image.dat", "r") as a:
    print(a.read().count('0'))
```